# Displaying data from a json array from external url with no api

Tags: json, reactjs, axios

I am having trouble trying to pull specific bits of data from a json. As you can see from the console log I can grab any number but i can't get any attribute such as artist or an image. I have two errors one being the colon placed on most attributes and secondly "Warning: Each child in a list should have a unique "key" prop."

I want to be able to return the information and display it on another componenet, so as you can see from the return I have a list of variables that I need in order to complete my project.

```
function Data() {
        const [Music, setMusic] = useState([], {});
    useEffect(() => {
      axios.get('https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/topalbums/limit=100/json')
      .then((data) => {
        setMusic(data.data.feed.entry);
        console.log(data.data.feed.entry[20]);
        })
        .catch((err) => console.log(err));
    },[]);
    
    
    
    
    
    
        return (
            <div>
                <h2>Album List</h2>
                 <ul className="albums">
                    {Music.map(Music => {
                    const  { id, name, image, label, title, artist } = Music;
                    return (
                    <div><li key={id.attributes.id}>
                    <img src={'/'} alt={"error"} />
                    <h2>{}</h2>
                    </li>
                    </div>
                    );
                    })}
                </ul>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't use the right key values. For instance, images are accessible from `im:image`, names from `im:name` and prices from `im:price`. [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/bold-moon-2q6x9?file=/src/App.js)

```
<li key={id.attributes['im:id']}>
                <img src={Music['im:image'][0].label} alt={'error'} />
                <h2>{Music['im:name'].label}</h2>
                <h2>{Music['im:price'].label}</h2>
              </li>
```

Comment: pls let me know if it solved your problem.

Comment: I have another question regarding above. How can I pass the data from this component to another component?

Comment: You can pass the data to other components as props. Please read this page (https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) in the react doc about props and components.

Comment: I have tried the different methods however I keep getting "item" is not defined

Comment: can you pls ask it in a different question and share the code there? then I would be able to answer your question according to more information